# Does cmd.exe enforce syntax rules for command-line utility programs?

Tags: command-line

I have run into several command-line utility (CLU) programs written in C or C++. All these programs that I've seen control options using a minus sign followed by the name of what is it that is being turned "on" or "off". For example, [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" utm.tif utm_tiled.tif
```

My question: why do CLU programs use the minus sign in this way? Is this simply something that is well accepted as good practice, something that is needed for a CLU program to work in cmd.exe, or is it something that C/C++ requires?

Comment: There is no "standard".  Just easy to parse, I guess.

Comment: you're mixing your environments. `cmd.exe` (which is a shell) runs in windows, and uses the convention of `/opt`, while Unix/linux etc also have shells, i.e. bash,ksh,zsh, etc where the standard, through using the function `getopts` (and other methods) is `-o -p -t -i -o -n`. You can compile a unix command in windows, and you can still use the `-o` form. You could write your own native windows cmd and also use `-o` options. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

More common I would say are the short/long form of arguments, example

```
-C <commit>, --reuse-message=<commit>
    Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the
    authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the
    commit.
```

This is perhaps because they can be parsed by [`getopt_long`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long). As far as the `-of` style goes, that is of course an option up to the programmer but would require a custom parser I believe.

[**ref**](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)